# Problema com Decimal (4,2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, mvc, sql-server-2014

Tenho um projeto MVC, estou utilizando Entity Framkework e em meu banco há uma tabela com uma coluna do tipo `decimal (4,2)`. O problema é:

Tento inserir um valor qualquer, por exemplo: `5.00 // 5,00 // 14.21 // 14,21` e sempre me retorna esse erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'. Não é possível converter um objeto
>   do tipo 'System.Decimal' no tipo 'System.String'. Descrição: Ocorreu
>   uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da
>   Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre
>   o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidCastException: Não é possível
>   converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Decimal' no tipo 'System.String'.

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado?

**EDIT**

Segue meu model, controller e minha view

> Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
[StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not contain more than 5 characters.")]
public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
```

> Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
return View();
}

//
// POST: /Department/Create

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Department department)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Departments.Add(department);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return View(department);
}
```

> View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Percentage)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Percentage)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Percentage)
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

O problema estva no DataAnnotation do Model. Estava tentando limitar o campo com [StringLength], tentei com [MaxLength] tbm dá erro, para limitar o campo e ao mesmo tempo validar o que deve ser digitado, utilizei essa DataAnnotation (Regex):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{1,2})(,\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")]
```

Comment: Qual banco utilizado? Qual a linguagem de acesso (C# com ADO.Net)?Qual a definição da sua tabela? Qual a query sendo executada? Aparentemente você esta tetando inserir uma `string` em um campo numérico, mas sem mais detalhe do seu problema e aplicação, não há como saber.

Comment: Provavelmente seu separador de decimal é o ponto, não?!

Comment: Tenho um projeto MVC 4, utilizando SQL Server, Entity Framework, blabla decimal (4,2) , digito isso no textbox do meu form e tento cadastrar, daí me retorna esse erro no browser.

@CelsoMarigoJr tentei com tudo, todos retornam o mesmo erro.

Comment: Como está sua VIEW e seu CONTROLLER?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa dei uma editada no tópico, confere lá, grato.

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: @RodrigoSpeller, acho que solucionei o problema, grato.

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria um *Binder* especial para decimais:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Registraria na aplicação toda:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
    }
}
```

Isto resolve valores para todo e qualquer decimal da aplicação.