# Converter 1.0 (string) para 1.0 (double) em c#

Tags: c#, variáveis, conversão

Boa noite pessoal,

estou tentando resolver um desafio em C# porém quando tento converter duas váriáveis string com ponto (Ex. 1.0 7.0) para duas variáveis double, perde o ponto e fica 10 70. Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
double x1 , x2;
Console.WriteLine();
value = Console.ReadLine();
String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);

x1 = Convert.ToDouble(substrings[0]);
x2 = Convert.ToDouble(substrings[1]);
```

Comment: Creio que o negativo tenha sido porque essa questão já foi respondida várias vezes aqui: [Problema com Decimal (4,2)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64662/problema-com-decimal-4-2?rq=1),[Problemas com a formatação do Double](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21291/problemas-com-a-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-double), etc..

Comment: Entendo, porém constatei uma forma diferente de resolver o problema, trocando o ponto por vírgula... talvez não seja a melhor prática mas funcionou também.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque o Convert.ToDouble utiliza os parametros de cultura definidos nas configurações do Windows.

Se realmente você quer que o ponto seja considerado separador decimal e não de milhar (como deve estar definido no seu computador)voce tem que usar a seguinte estrutura:

[Convert.ToDouble (String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9s9ak971%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Exemplo:

```
double x1 , x2;
Console.WriteLine();
value = Console.ReadLine();
String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);

x1 = Convert.ToDouble(substrings[0],new CultureInfo("en-US"));
x2 = Convert.ToDouble(substrings[1],new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Veja funcionado no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wg81ws)

Comment: Obrigada William, na verdade troquei o ponto por vírgula e também deu certo. 

substrings[0] = substrings[0].Replace(".", ",");

 Mas vi mesmo que existe essa questão e depois vou testar dessa maneira.